# Is there a way to launch p4v to display a single changelist?

Tags: perforce

I am familiar with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> shortcut to display a single changelist in p4v.

I would like to known if I can achieve the same from the command line, while p4v is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different P4V components that you can launch from the command line, depending on your version of P4V.  Check out:

https://www.perforce.com/blog/p4v-secrets-calling-p4v-command-line

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.1/manuals/p4v/advanced_options.p4vc.html

'p4vc change XXXXX' with the changelist number launches the changelist window.

Comment: 'p4vc change XXXXX' with the changelist number works ! Thanks.